# Java JDBC Inserting Foreign Key

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

i'm new to Java and doing a homework. I have two relational tables and i do not know how is the best way to insert the foreign key. That is my code:

```
 String sql = "INSERT INTO verkoper (voornaam, naam, email) VALUES (?,?,?)";

            preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(sql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
            preparedStatement.setString(1, txtVoornaam.getText());
            preparedStatement.setString(2, txtNaam.getText());
            preparedStatement.setString(3, txtEmail.getText());

            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();


            myRs = preparedStatement.getGeneratedKeys();
            myRs.next();



String sql2 = "INSERT INTO boek (naam, auteur, uitgever, taal, jaar, verkoperid) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

            preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(sql2);
            preparedStatement.setString(1, txtBoekNaam.getText());
            preparedStatement.setString(2, txtAuteur.getText());
            preparedStatement.setString(3, txtUitgever.getText());
            preparedStatement.setString(4, txtTaal.getText());
            preparedStatement.setString(5, txtJaar.getText());           
            preparedStatement.setString(6, Integer.toString(myRs.getInt(1)) );
            preparedStatement.execute();
```

Comment: You should get your new verkoper's primary key (in a variable) before the second SQL Query because you have to close your `ResultSet` before your `PreparedStatement`. So close both before that line `preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(sql2);`. 
If you work with Java >= 7 (I think yes), you should consider using "Try with resources" (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) on your `Connection`, `PreparedStatement`and `ResultSet` objects to close it properly.

Comment: BTW, always check that ResultSet.next() returns true before trying to retrieve objects from the ResultSet.

Comment: @Dorian Thanx. Should i close my connection too?

Comment: Yes, you should close your connection (and all of your resources) as soon as possible. In that case, you can use the same connection to execute the 2 queries. But never forget to close resources, it may produce memory leaks. Try-with-resources is a good way to do it, it guarantees that your resources will be closed, whatever it happens, so use it :)